# RESTful Web Service - Taking data from a form and grabbing info from MySQL database

Tags: java, web-services, rest

I have a database of Students that have to log into a course advisor website using their email and password.  I've hard-coded some students in the database to test this and I have the Facade doing what it needs to do but I'm so confused on the Services part of it and how the webpage sends the data to the service and calls the Facade methods I've created. Here's some code.

```
@Path("/Students/{email}")
@GET
@Produces("text/plain")
@Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
public static Student getStudent(@FormParam("studentpass") String password, @FormParam("studentemail") String email)
{
    PlannerFacade pf = new PlannerFacade();
    Student x = pf.getStudent(email, password); //returns null if the password does not match the one in the Database.  Else returns the Student's toString();
    return x;
}
```

I'm confused on how the paths work with the {email}, and how they work in general.

Here is my javascript code:

```
function getStud(responseType) {
    var status=0;
    var theEmail = document.getElementById("studform").studentmail.value;
    var url = "http://localhost:8080/CP/Students/"+theEmail;
    alert(url);
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
      {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
    else
      {// code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
      {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
        document.getElementById("x").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
      };
    xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
};
```

Right now I just have a blank div set as 'x' and I'm just trying to see if I can get the script to call the services right and change the div with the id of 'x' to display the Student's info.  Classmates of mine were talking about using a combination of JQuery and Ajax is there anything you all know that would make this easier to comprehend?

Comment: What's the purpose of {email}? Like do you want to identify each resource uniquely by email address?

Comment: Yes, each student has an email and password in the database.  I compare the password in the database with the password that's supposed to be passed through on the form and return null if they don't match.  If they do match I want to return the Student's toString just for debuggin purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so there is a lot going on here.

First, your service endpoint should look more like this:

```
@Path("/students/{username}")
@GET
@Produces("application/json")
public Student getStudent(@HeaderParam("password") String password, @PathParam("username") String username)
```

Let me explain:

- I made it so the path will be something like "/students/bob." An actual E-mail with its special characters could add weirdness you don't want to deal with at this stage of your learning.
- I put the password in the HTTP headers. This is insecure too, but I couldn't bear to put it in the path.
- The respective locations of these parameters indicate the reason I have `@PathParam` and `@HeaderParam`.
- No need for `static`.
- You produce JSON because apparently you want to send a `Student` object back. This means you need to populate a `Student` object with the data you fetch from the database and serialize it to JSON that the REST client can read.

You will do something like this once you've fetched your data from MySQL:

```
Student s = new Student("Bob Smith");
s.setStatus("Passing");
//just all the stuff you need to create a Student in Java.
```

Then you will need to configure your REST framework to use a JSON serializer (like [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson), [GSON](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/), etc) to convert this Java object into JSON that looks like this:

```
{'name':'Bob Smith', 'status': 'Passing'}
```

If configured properly, the conversion will "just work." Then your JavaScript REST client will know what to do with the resulting JSON.

As for the JavaScript, your students are right. Use an abstraction rather than fiddle around with the low-level details of the DOM and XHR. JQuery is as good as any. You can find information on how to use JQuery's `$.post` [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/). Come to think of it, maybe we should do one of our video tutorials on this topic.

Hope this helps.

Comment: But I'm trying to grab a student's info from my SQL database, why would I use post for that?

Comment: Oh. I was confused because you are doing a lot of stuff that looks like a post. Made an edit.

Comment: Oh okay, so if I'm creating a new Student object when this method produces JSON, wouldn't I have to parse it back into JAVA variables for the getStudent() ?

Comment: If I didn't want to parse the data back into JSON could I just return a String from the getStudent in the services?

Comment: Of course. Then just do `@Produces("text/plain")
public String getStudent` If I make a tutorial on this for the YouTube channel, you better watch and tell your friends haha.

Comment: If you made a tutorial on this stuff I'd subscribe and spread you knowledge around the entire Computer Science study body in my University.  We're all having trouble with this.

Comment: I appreciate that haha. I'm working on a Python one now, but a REST tutorial will be coming soon. Let me know via Twitter or whatever you want if there is something in particular I should cover.